# Highlighting duplicate <ul></ul> menu navigation's

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to design a site for someone who wants both the Contact Us page in the bottom portion of the menu and above their logo in the top right corner.

As such here is the client code:

This is the top menu above the logo:

```
<ul class="topnavigation" style="width:1000px; border-bottom-style: none;  height: 40px;">
        <li class="highlight" style="width:100px; height: 40px; font-family:Calibri; float:right;"><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li style="width:100px; height:40px; font-family:Calibri; border-left:1px solid white; border-right:1px solid white; float:right;"><a href="StartPage.aspx">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And this is the menu under the logo:

```
   <ul class="navigation" style="width:1000px; height:40px; border-bottom:none;">
    <li style="width:150px; font-family:Calibri; height: 40px; border-right:1px solid white;"><a href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
    <li style="width:150px; font-family:Calibri; border-right:1px solid white; height: 40px;"><a href="Application.aspx">Applications</a></li>
    <li style="width:200px; font-family:Calibri; border-right:1px solid white; height: 40px;"><a href="FeaturesAndBenefits.aspx">Features and Benefits</a></li>
    <li style="width:200px; font-family:Calibri; border-right:1px solid white; height: 40px;"><a href="TechnicalSpecs.aspx">Technical Specs</a></li>
    <li style="width:150px; font-family:Calibri; border-right:1px solid white; height: 40px;"><a href="ContactUs.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="width:145px; font-family:Calibri; border-right:none; height: 40px;"><a href="Recognition.aspx">Recognition</a></li>
        </ul>
```

To highlight which page the user selected I used some javascript (which I have been trying to learn lately) and CSS

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var str = location.href.toLowerCase();

$('.topnavigation li a').each(function () {
    if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
    }
});

$('.navigation li a').each(function () {
    if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
    }
});
});
```

CSS:

```
ul.navigation
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
background-color:#0071BB;
height:34px;
border-bottom:none;
}

ul.navigation li
{ 

float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;

}
ul.navigation li a:last-child{}


ul.navigation a
{
color:white;
display: block;
padding: 8px 8px;
text-decoration: none;
 }
 /*background color of LI*/
 ul.navigation li.highlight
 {
 background:Darkblue;
 }
 /*Text color for A*/
 ul.navigation li.highlight a
 { 
color:white;
  }
 ul.navigation li:hover
{
color:white;
background-color:darkblue;
background: darkblue;
 }

a, a:visited
{
color:#000;
 }



ul.topnavigation
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
background-color:#0071BB;
height:34px;
border-bottom:none;
}

ul.topnavigation li
{ 

float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;

}
ul.topnavigation li a:last-child{}


ul.topnavigation a
{
color:white;
display: block;
padding: 8px 8px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/*background color of LI*/
ul.topnavigation li.highlight
{
 background:Darkblue;
}
/*Text color for A*/
ul.topnavigation li.highlight a
{ 
color:white;
}
ul.topnavigation li:hover
{
color:white;
background-color:darkblue;
background: darkblue;
}
```

With this implementation if the user clicks on any page it highlights the page. But if they click on the Contact Us in the top corner is only highlights the Contact Us in the bottom menu and not the top menu. I found that strange and is a question in itself for me because I would expect it to highlight the top portion and not the bottom portion. (If anyone can answer that as well I would appreciate it - because I don't see how it is recognizing it).

So, how can I have both the top contact page navigation and bottom contact page navigation highlight at the same time. I am assuming that this will be done with java script and not on the C# code.

I have attempted to combine the two such as

```
  $('.navigation li a' & '.topnavigation li a').each(function () {
```

but realized this probably wouldn't work because it is indexing. Although I am not sure. I attempted to set them as an "if equivalent" so if both href were the same then it would highlight them. Nothing I have done has worked (although amusingly I have gotten some odd results highlighting other navs).

So, any suggestions? Point me in the right direction? Something I am not seeing or how can this be done? Is this going to be needed to be done in C#? Can JavaScript do it?

Please let me know. This is the first question I have asked so I am frustrated on this.

Comment: have you ever heard about [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @KingKing Sort of. I am new to all of this. But what would fiddle matter as opposed to me testing and running it on VS 2013? Or am I not understanding fiddle?

Comment: I think he's suggesting that you should set up a fiddle that demonstrates the issue, so people can help you fix it.

Comment: +1 KingKing because I have not used fiddle and this is pretty nifty. I was thinking it was something else.

Comment: Head on over to http://jsfiddle.net/ and setup a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't need an each here, nor do you need to combine selectors unless you're doing something special based on their root class. You just need a way to match things up. Here is a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/AEY5h/

EDIT: The original code still works (you need to remove `e.preventDefault();` for your site)

```
 $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // just for this demo
        var thisHREF = $(this).attr('href'); // get the href of the clicked item
        $('li').removeClass('highlight'); // remove all the classes
        $('a[href="' + thisHREF + '"]').closest('li').addClass('highlight'); // add the class to the items that have the same href
    });
```

To highlight the elements where your page matches up add the following (outside of the above block)-

```
var currentPage = location.pathname.substring(1);
$('a[href="' + currentPage + '"]').closest('li').addClass('highlight'); // adds highlight to current page element
```

In the fiddle I have replaced the location info with jsfiddle's info so that both Contact Us elements are highlighted - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/AEY5h/1/

Comment: You may want to start with http://learn.jquery.com which is really interactive and makes the concepts very clear. You're well on your way to understanding things, you'll be great in no time!

Comment: I will - looking at the link. One last question. I am assuming e.preventDefault() method is used for fiddle to show it highlights without actually "blowing up", but when I comment it out on asp.net it only highlights the Contact Us tab in the top right. I am messing with it now, but why is this?

Comment: preventDefault() is just preventing the click from having its normal action of following a link. I just placed it there for the demo in jsfiddle. Are you wanting to highlight on hover or some other event? It should work exactly the same way in your ASP pages.

Comment: I am still messing with this. Yea, I am wanting it to highlight both when clicked. When I remove the e.preventDefault(); it only highlights the top Contact Us. if I keep it - it works but wont redirect pages (as expected)...Strange it works with the method for the demo but doesn't when removed.

Comment: Aha! you're expecting that the item will be highlighted on another page after the click has occurred. In order to do that you have to do something slightly different with your code. Let me make some changes.

Comment: exactly. I am expecting them to both be highlighted. What gfullam did below works halfway as well except with his code the contact us in the top right never goes un-highlighted.  BTW I am looking at that link you gave me and I am very appreciative for it.

Comment: I copied the javascript out and posted it. Commented the   //  e.preventDefault(); but it still does not work. It redirects to a new page but only highlights the top right contact us

Comment: Hmmmm....have you checked the href values in each link? There is something weird going on here because it works with the markup that you provided (which was copied to the fiddle). Do you have a link to the page?

Comment: First, remove class="highlight" from the li in the header in every page. The JavaScript must also be included on every page in order for this to work. Where are you including the JavaScript?

Comment: I removed the highlight. Nothing will highlight now. I took the javascript out of the js file and I put it on the MasterPage under the <script>

Comment: I still see the class="highlight" on each page and I don't see the JavaScript code. You're also including jQuery twice, once at the top of the page and once near the end. I see the code now.

Comment: Removed it now. Sorry updated it. the script is under the div class banner under the div main body

Comment: Can you place the script in the head of the document, right after you load jQuery? I'm also doing some things and I find that location.href comes back as undefined.

Comment: I got it working! I used gfullams code (see below) but the reason I wasn't getting that to work was because as you mentioned I had already had the class="highlight" inserted in my code that needed to be removed. I have updated it now. The java script file highlightNav.js that you can inspect.

Comment: I do have to say I find it odd though when you load the page that is doesn't automatically highlight the home button... What is your take on that?

Comment: OK - I also just made an edit to my code to get the location pathname (see above). And Home does highlight for me when I load the page. My only caution on @gfullams code is that it uses a lot of overhead where none is really required (combined selectors, each loop).

Comment: Your code works as well. The most recently updated version of it. I have given you the correct answer since you worked with me through all of this (I don't understand the overheard concept yet - june 16th 2013 was the first day I programmed a single lick of code so I am not even a year into it yet). I am going to read, practice and understand this and will figure out how to have the home button display the darkblue on pageload on my own. I have much to learn. Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine jQuery selectors using a comma like this:

```
$('.navigation li a, .topnavigation li a').each(function () {
```

Notice that the comma is included inside the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

### jQuery errors, Remove default .highlight class from list-items

In your `.topnavigation` menu, don't provide preselected `.highlight` classes.

You have a preselected item with class `.highlight`, which may be why it appears that your script is working to highlight the item in your `.topnavigation` menu, but not your `.navigation` menu.

Also, your jQuery has some errors and I recommend combining selectors since the .each() function is the same for both.

This corrected version should do the trick (if there are no preselected items with `.highlight`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
    $('.topnavigation li a, .navigation li a').each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf($(this).attr('href').toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
        }
    });
});
```

Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfullam/0rppzomt/

Comment: How would one not have the entire top navigation highlighted, such as what this one does?

Comment: actually this continuously highlights the top contact us

Comment: @AndrewBringaze I updated the example to get rid of the unnecessary `.removeClass()` method and provided a link to a working JSFiddle. The key to this solution is to not provide a preselected item with `.highlight` already applied.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to combine multiple selectors into one with jQuery is not like this:

```
$('.navigation li a' & '.topnavigation li a')
```

but rather like this:

```
$('.navigation li a, .topnavigation li a')
```

[Here's a link](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to more documentation on the multiple selector usage. Make that change in your javascript and you should properly be selecting all the elements you're trying to target.

Comment: +1 for the link. Reading it, maybe it will help. Interesting in itself.